# Specflow expected value with Unicode characters behave different than expected

Tags: c#, character-encoding, specflow

We format a date like so:

```
dateTime.Value.ToString("d\u00A0MMMM\u00A0yyyy")
```

this keeps the date parts together in the printed text.

In our specflow feature file we want to check some of these strings with these dates in them:

```
| ExpectedMessage                           |
| your new appointment is on 1XjanuariX2019 |
```

Which character needs to go at spots marked with 'X'

We tried '\\u00A0' '\u00A0' with and without semicolon at the end and the plain  space

Comment: You probably want to just write them as is: "1 january 2019" (< those are not spaces but \u00A0) and save your file in UTF-8 encoding (if not already).

Comment: @Evk  Can I change the encoding of the specflow feature files? And when I do how do I insert the \u00A0 into the sample text?

Comment: As far as I know, feature files are just regular text files, so you can save them as any other text file. Most likely they are already unicode. As for how to insert it there, not really sure, you can try sites such as this one: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/